# How to append items from a select statement individually into a list?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am making a casino as a school project and I'm making a way for players to view their last 5 games,
so far my code for this goes as follows

```
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P1_Outcome, P2_Outcome, P3_Outcome, P4_Outcome, P5_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}' ORDER BY RecordID DESC LIMIT 5 """)
playeroutcomes = (cursor.fetchone())
```

however as you may assume that'll give me all outcomes in 1 variable which isn't what I want. I want to append each item(P1_outcome, P2_outcome etc) to a list one at a time so I can then iterate through it and show the respective outcomes.

I can achieve this very inefficiently by doing this

```
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P1_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}'""")
playeroutcomes.append(cursor.fetchone())
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P2_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}'""")
playeroutcomes.append(cursor.fetchone())
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P3_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}'""")
playeroutcomes.append(cursor.fetchone())
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P4_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}'""")
playeroutcomes.append(cursor.fetchone())
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P5_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}'""")
playeroutcomes.append(cursor.fetchone())
```

however since I want to show the last 5 games this would be way too many lines to justify.
Any idea how I can do this? I'm very new to sqlite so apologies if my code sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the results into a list with `[*playeroutcomes] = cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: @abxty if you find the answer useful you can ✔️

Comment: sorry i have one more question, I tried using the statement  cursor.execute(f"""SELECT P1_Outcome, P2_Outcome, P3_Outcome, P4_Outcome, P5_Outcome FROM Game_History WHERE username = '{username}' ORDER BY RecordID DESC LIMIT 5 """)    [*playeroutcomes] = cursor.fetchone()             but it only returns me the last row not the other 4, any clue why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlite, but from documentation, `fetchone` is, as it's named, only supposed to return one row. You probably want to use `fetchmany` or `fetchall`.